# Trim / strip zeros of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**How to remove leading / trailing zeros of a numpy array?**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,0,3,2,-1,0,0,7,9,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

#Desired output
[3,2,-1,0,0,7,9,13]
```

This doesn't work:

```
a[a != 0]
```

because it would remove *all zeros* including the zeros which are *inside*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`numpy.trim_zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.trim_zeros.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0,0,0,3,2,-1,0,0,7,9,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
>>> np.trim_zeros(a)
array([ 3,  2, -1,  0,  0,  7,  9, 13])
```

Comment: Nice! I was not aware of this function and my first idea was `w = np.where(a!=0)[0]; a[w[0]:w[-1]+1]` which is not as robust for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 3):

To trim 2d arrays:

```
def trim_zeros_2D(array, axis=1):
    mask = ~(array==0).all(axis=axis)
    inv_mask = mask[::-1]
    start_idx = np.argmax(mask == True)
    end_idx = len(inv_mask) - np.argmax(inv_mask == True)
    if axis:
        return array[start_idx:end_idx,:]
    else:
        return array[:, start_idx:end_idx]
```

Comment: An explanation of the logic of your function would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

To trim 2d arrays without an extra function:

```
np.array([np.trim_zeros(arr) for arr in array2d])
```

Simple list comprehension wrapped by array should work fine.